# .NET TraceSource not working under Windows Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, trace, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to display some `TraceSource` logging information to the Azure emulator (*consoley*) window.

None of the `TraceSource` lines are displayed. Only the stock `Trace` lines and various low level azure messages.

Here's my steps to repo, including code snippets:

1. File -> New -> Cloud Service (SDK 2.0) -> (add worker role).
2. Add a TraceSource to the WorkerRole.
3. Update the app.config with tracing data.
4. Play/Publish.

**NOTE** all the other default code is in there, such as the `.csfg` which says to use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` etc

#### Worker Role code.

This is the STOCK DEFAULT CODE with my `TraceSource` coded *added*...

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace WorkerRole1
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        private TraceSource _traceSource;

        public override void Run()
        {
            _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0,
                                    "********************** 111111111111111111111 ******************* ");

            // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
            Trace.TraceInformation("WorkerRole1 entry point called", "Information");

            while (true)
            {
                _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 0,
                                        "********************** 222222222222222222222 ******************* ");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

            // For information on handling configuration changes
            // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.


            _traceSource = new TraceSource("Azure.WorkerRole", SourceLevels.All);

            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Now the app.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <system.diagnostics>

        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="AzureListener"
                 type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>

        <sources>
            <source name="Azure.WorkerRole" switchValue="Verbose" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="AzureListener" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>

    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

That's it! run and see that the `traceSource` stuff isn't getting displayed :( The `Trace.Information` stuff is .. but I don't want to use the old `Trace` method because that is suggested to be replaced by using `TraceSource` instead.

Sample output. Notice only the `Trace` lines are getting added (along with the low level azure stuff).

[image]

Comment: This is a really good question. I was having some problems with trace configuration and this nearly drove me crazy. You should find that your codes write to actual diagnostic log in the cloud with no problem, but for some reason the local emulator is hard-wired to accept only events from the Trace class.